# requests' MissingSchema exception for Invalid URL

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape content from a website but I am getting the below mentioned error

The method:

```
def scrape_newtimes():

    """Scrapes content from the NewTimes"""

    url = 'https://www.newtimes.co.rw/'

    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    tree = fromstring(r.content)

    links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="x-small-push clearfix"]/a/@href')

    for link in links:
        r = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS)
        blog_tree = fromstring(r.content)

        paras = blog_tree.xpath('//div[@class="article-content"]/p')
        para = extract_paratext(paras)
        text = extract_text(para)
        if not text:
            continue
        yield '"%s" %s' % (text, link)
```

The error I am getting:

```
>>> sc = scrape_newtimes()
>>> string_1 = next(sc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Projects\bird\bird-env\bot.py", line 58, in scrape_newtimes
    r = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS)
  File "D:\Projects\bird\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\bird\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\bird\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "D:\Projects\bird\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "D:\Projects\bird\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 313, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "D:\Projects\bird\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 387, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/news/londons-kings-college-launch-civil-service-programme-rwanda': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///news/londons-kings-college-launch-civil-service-programme-rwanda?
>>>
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of the error traceback rather than posting a screenshot of it - however the error is telling you that the url you are requesting is missing the protocol schema. It looks like it's a relative url. Perhaps you need to concatenate your variable `url` with each `link` before you can make a request to the link url.

Comment: @ChidG Check I have added the screen shot. what should I do

Answer (score 0):

The exception basically tells you what is wrong:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/news/londons-kings-college-launch-civil-service-programme-rwanda': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///news/londons-kings-college-launch-civil-service-programme-rwanda?
```

Or with line wrapping the line:

```
Invalid URL '/news/londons-kings-college-launch-civil-service-programme-rwanda': 
No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant
http:///news/londons-kings-college-launch-civil-service-programme-rwanda?
```

You `link` does not contain a complete URL

Comment: How do I concatenate the above **url** to the **link**

Comment: @RwandaNkunda try https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin